# vim: How to format code block after typing a certain character?

Tags: vim, code-formatting

I want to perform auto-formatting on a certain code block, after a specific character has been typed, similar to visual studio's auto-formatting.

For example, when an endline character has been typed, the previous line could be formatted, like one were hitting `Vgq` on that line.

What is the easiest and most efficient way to achieve this?
I already thought about using the `InsertCharPre` event, but I actually would need a `InsertCharPost` event. Unfortunately that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if  `format code block` you meant is `gq`, you could try:

```
inoremap <cr> <esc>Vgqo
```

this mapping does: when you type <kbd>Enter</kbd> in INSERT mode, it will does automatically `vgq` for you, and place cursor in next line, staying in INSERT mode.

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of remapping keys yet. For now, that works just fine!